# Mismatch in counting system jiffies and /proc/stat in Linux

Tags: linux

I am checking `/proc/stat` for system statistics, in Ubuntu 16.10 x86_64, kernel HZ is set to `250`.

In `bash`, I ran:

```
cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu ' && sleep 1 && cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu '
```

After that, I found with 1 second sleeping in `bash`, the total jiffies passed away is `400`, not `250`.
(I summed up all the 10 numbers).

I don't know why there is the mismatch in the total passed jiffies. Please help me better understanding `/proc/stat`.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think the sum of the jiffies (USER_HZ) (generally hundredths of a second) would only be related to `sleep`? What about `cat` (and all the myriad of other processes, system I/O, any virtual hosts, etc.? (look at `man 5 proc` under `/proc/stat`)

Comment: Well, the `cpu` line is the accumulation of all the `cpuX` values, but the only explanation of how it is measured is `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` (which of course -- varies by architecture). So I don't have a final answer for you, but I suspect your additional jiffies are due to the system doing what it needs to do during that same period of time, which is reflected in the `/proc/stat` values...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin. My goal is to validate which fields of /proc/stat are contributed to the total CPU time.
The jiffies is another format of time, as a period of time elapses, the jiffies is accumulated accordingly to reflect the period of time. And I use sleep 1 for the elapse of time.

Maybe I am wrong, it would be appreciated if you can point it out.

jiffies shown in /proc/stat is with 250 as HZ or USER_HZ?? If it uses USER_HZ (100) it makes sense.

Comment: I found why the mismatch, according to David comments and manpage of /proc/stat.
The /proc/stat shows the jiffies in unit of USER_HZ (e.g. 100), not the HZ used in kernel.
So, in my testing with Ubuntu16.04, the laptop has 4 CPUs, the sleep 1 will get the 400 jiffies accumulated for 4 CPUs.

Thanks David for comments.